# An awk script without hard-coded field information

Tags: awk

We have the following `awk` script that extracts fields 6, 7 and 14 from a CSV file:

```
awk -F, '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (i in [6, 7, 14]) printf "%s,", $i; print ""}' $input_file
```

The script works beautifully, except that the information about the fields of interest is hard-coded.  We would like to be able to pass this information as a single command line argument (or even a series of command line arguments), to make the script more versatile.  We tried a few things, including the following, but we keep getting a syntax error:

```
awk -F, '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (i in ['$2']) printf "%s,", $i; print ""}' $input_file
```

Comment: `i in [6, 7, 14]` does not work with GNU Awk. What dialect is this?

Comment: you can "embed" shell arguments as you have done, switching from single-quotes to dbl-quotes as needed, but I recommend you read about `awk -v arg1="val1" -v arg2="val2" '{if ($2 > val1 && $3 == val2) print}'` sort of coding. Good luck.

Comment: In any case, assuming `$2` expands to something like `5, 6, 7`, which contains spaces, you need this:   `... in ['"$2"'] ...`.  It's not enough to close and re-open the single quote: you must also put a double quote around `$2` to protect its expansion from field-splitting on whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F, '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (i in [6, 7, 14]) printf "%s,", $i; print ""}' $input_file
```

is not valid awk syntax which is one reason why

```
awk -F, '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (i in ['$2']) printf "%s,", $i; print ""}' $input_file
```

or any variation of it would also give you a syntax error.

This is probably what you're trying to do:

```
awk -F, -v vals="$2" '
    BEGIN { split(vals,tmp); for (i in tmp) arr[tmp[i]] }
    { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (i in arr) printf "%s,", $i; print "" }
' "$input_file"
```

assuming `$2` contains a comma-separated string like `6,7,14` and your input file is a CSV with unquoted fields.

That would still print a trailing `,` on each line and looping through all fields and discarding the ones you don't want for every input line is an inefficient way to do what you're trying to do. This would solve both of those additional problems:

```
awk -v vals="$2" '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS=","; n=split(vals,arr) }
    { for (i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%s%s", $(arr[i]), (i<n ? OFS : ORS) }
' "$input_file"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to not use (g)awk, and use `cut`:

```
cut -d "," -f "6,7,14" inputfile
```

(or: `a="6,7,14"; cut -d "," -f "$a" inputfile`)

When input contains:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,2,25,26
```

output should look like:

```
f,g,n
6,7,14
```